# bootstrap btn-toolbar pull-right in navbar not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and trying to keep my buttons at the right on all screens and browsers. On IE, the buttons stay to the right, but on chrome, they are only on the right on small screens. How do I make them stay to the right on all screens. I have tried pull-right to the buttons indiviudally with no luck and now I have applied to the the btn-toolbar and still no luck. ANY ideas on the issue?

```js
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Grid</a>
          <p class="navbar-btn">
               <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                    <a href="d.htm" target="_blank" id="info" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a>
                   <a href="B.html" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
                </p>
          </div>
    </div>
                   
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are missing a

This worked for me.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Grid</a>
                <p class="navbar-btn">
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                <p class="navbar-btn">
                </p>
                <a href="d.htm" target="_blank" id="info" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a>
                <a href="B.html" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: almost, but now when the screen is scaled the buttons drop to another row. I need them to stay on the same row. This happens on IE and chrome.